How to debug why my elixir app is crashing in kubernetes environment
I'm trying to deploy my app in our internal Kubernetes instance. My Dockerfile is the standard one generated from mix release here is the logs of the container.
08:13:08.050 [info] Running Todo.Endpoint with Bandit 1.5.4 at :::8080 (http)
08:13:08.050 [info] Access Todo.Endpoint at https://todo.example.com
08:13:08.054 [notice] Application todo exited: shutdown
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ("{application_terminated,todo,shutdown}")

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...%

I cannot ssh into the container and read erl_crash.dump because the container is in CrashLoopBackOff state. 99% that the problem is related to connecting to the database, but I cannot debug.
